# How to put User Input to end the loop on c#

Tags: c#

Im new to programming in C# and i encountered some problems, I am trying to create a countdown Console Command but im stuck on how to terminate the loop using a user input (in this case, when the user presses the "Enter" Button)

Here is the code that I currently have

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

class stopWatch {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine ("Access The Clock? Y/N");
    string yN = Console.ReadLine();
    if ((yN == "y") || (yN == "Y")) {
      Console.WriteLine ("Timer (T) or Stopwatch (S)?");
      var sT = Console.ReadLine();
      if ((sT == "s") || (sT == "S")) {
        Console.WriteLine ("Press the 'Enter' Button to Start");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Stopwatch Started");
        Console.WriteLine("Press the 'Enter' Button again to Stop");
        for(int i = 0; i >= 0; i ++) {
          Console.WriteLine(i);
          Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
      }
    }
    else if ((yN =="n") || (yN == "N")) {
      Console.WriteLine ("Alright, Thank You");
      Environment.Exit(0);
    }
    else {
      Console.WriteLine ("Wrong Input");
      Environment.Exit (0);
    }
  }
}
```

keep in mind im very new to c# and loops, i'm getting a hard time translating and trying on everything, it'd be really grateful of me to get an extra explanation for your answers

Comment: Have you considered using a while loop?

Comment: There isn't a loop in the code posted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use separate thread for that. Threads is advanced theme, but the basic goal is to do several things at once (in your example run stopwatch and wait for user input). Here is full working code based on your sample:

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp13
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Access The Clock? Y/N");
            string yN = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

            if (yN == "y")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Timer (T) or Stopwatch (S)?");
                var sT = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

                if (sT == "s")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Press the 'Enter' Button to Start");
                    Console.ReadLine();

                    bool runStopWatch = true;
                    Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        for (int i = 0;; i++)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(i);
                            Thread.Sleep(1000);

                            if (!runStopWatch)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    Console.WriteLine("Stopwatch Started");
                    Console.WriteLine("Press the 'Enter' Button again to Stop");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    runStopWatch = false;
                }
            }
            else if (yN == "n")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Alright, Thank You");
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong Input");
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Task.Run` starts a new thread, so your stopwatch runs independent of the main thread (which waits for user to press Enter). Variable `runStopWatch` is shared between threads (don't think about it right now), so when main thread sets it to `false`, stopwatch's thread sees it and terminated the loop.

Side mote. More proper way to do this is to use [CancellationToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken?view=netcore-3.1) istead of bool variable. But again. don't worry about it right now.

Comment: If I may ask, why did you use Boolean there?

Comment: To communicate information between threads. Could you please ask more specific question? What don't you understand about that boolean variable?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're new im going to try to explain it as simple as possible. The solution you're trying to create is a solution to a multi-threaded problem. This means you will have to do an action while another action takes place. This can be resolved using async methods, this might be too advanced for now, so I will suggest reading up on loops and then multi-threaded programming first.

But for an answer i will have to refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27580241/breaking-from-a-loop-with-button-click-c-sharp) post here on how to fix this particular problem. (Look at the second part of the accepted answer).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :D